# Delphi FMX 10.3: Issues with obtaining file properties in for multi-platform applications

Tags: delphi, filesystems, firemonkey

I am seeking to convert some Delphi code to extract file properties from the operating system from a time-honoured implementation for the Windows platform to a new implementation for the Android platform.

I have found that whereas the implementation for the Delphi platform uses the functions `FindFirst()` and `FindNext()` without problem and allows the file properties to be obtained from the `TSearchRec` parameter, this approach doesn’t appear to work for the Android platform.

So I need to find cross-platform functions to obtain file and directory properties. Several properties may be obtained using methods of the `System.IOUtils` record types `TDirectory` and `TFile`. But for some reason, these does not appear to include a method to obtain the size in bytes of a file.

Therefore, I have tried to obtain the file size by creating a `TFileStream` object for the file given its pathname, and then getting the size from the `TFileStream.Size` property. This method works when the file is not already open. However if the file is open, then an exception is thrown.

The next question, then, is how to find out whether a file is open before calling `TFileStream.Create()`. This ought to be straightforward, but I cannot remember how to do it. So I have tried the following global procedure:

```pascal
procedure FXGetFileSize(FilePathname: string; var FileInUse: Boolean;
                            var Size: int64);
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  try
    FileStream:= TFileStream.Create(FilePathname, fmOpenRead);
    try
      FileInUse:= False;
      Size:= FileStream.Size;
    finally
      FileStream.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      begin
        FileInUse:= True;
        Size:= 0;
        FileStream.Free;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

I call this procedure from within the following method:

```pascal
procedure TFolder.ReadFX (Pathname: string; Recurse: Boolean);
{Reads details of folder file components in a folder  into a TFolder data structure – cross-platform version}
var
    Separator: char;
    FolderPaths: TStringDynArray;
    FilePathNames: TStringDynArray;
    i: integer;
    FolderPathI: string;
    FilePathnameI: string;
    SubFolder: TFolder;
    SubFileCpt: TFileCpt;
    SubFileCptIndex: integer;
    FolderCptName: string;
    Datetime: TDatetime;
    FileInUse: Boolean;
    FileSize: int64;
  begin
    Separator:= TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    FCount:= 0;
    FCumSize:= 0;
    FCumFileCount:= 0;
    FCumFolderCount:= 1;
    {Extract list of subfolders in directory:}
    FolderPaths:= TDirectory.GetDirectories(Pathname);
    {Create a TFolder object for each subfolder:}
    for i:= 0 to High(FolderPaths) do
      begin
        FolderPathI:= FolderPaths[i];
        if TDirectory.Exists(FolderPathI) then
          begin
            try
              {Create TFolder object for subfolder i:}
              SubFolder:= TFolder.Create;
              AddFolderCpt(SubFolder, SubFileCptIndex);
              {Assign TFolder properties:}
              FolderCptName:= StringReplace(FolderPathI, (Pathname + Separator), '', [rfIgnoreCase]);
              Subfolder.Name:= FolderCptName;
              {Subfolder.Name:= Path; }
              Subfolder.FDateTime:= TDirectory.GetLastWriteTime(FolderPathI);
              {Recursively process subfolder:}
              if Recurse then
                Subfolder.Read(FolderPathI, Recurse);
              {Compute aggregate properties:}
              FCumSize:= FCumSize + SubFolder.FCumSize;
              FCumFileCount:= FCumFileCount + SubFolder.FCumFileCount;
              FCumFolderCount:= FCumFolderCount + SubFolder.FCumFolderCount;
            except
              on E: Exception do
                begin
                  E.Message:= 'Error in TFolder.ReadFX processing folder "'
                     + FolderPathI + '"' + #13#10
                     + '(' + E.Message + ')';
                end;
              end;
            end;
        end;
    {Get list of files in directory:}
    FilePathNames:= TDirectory.GetFiles(Pathname);
    {Create TFileCpt objects for each child file:}
    for i:= 0 to High(FilePathnames) do
      begin
        FilePathnameI:= FilePathnames[i];
        if (FilePathnameI<> '.') and (FilePathnameI<>'..') then
          begin
            try
              {$ifdef MSWINDOWS}
              if not ([TFileAttribute.faHidden, TFileAttribute.faSystem] <=
                                    TFile.GetAttributes(FilePathnameI)) then
              {$endif}
                begin
                  FXGetFileSize(FilePathnameI, FileInUse, FileSize);      {***}
                  {Create a TFileCpt object corresponding to FilePathnameI:}
                  SubFileCpt:= TFileCpt.Create;
                  AddFolderCpt(SubFileCpt, SubFileCptIndex);
                  {Assign TFileCpt properties:}
                  SubFileCpt.FName:= TPath.GetFileName(FilePathnameI);
                  SubFileCpt.FSize:= FileSize;
                  SubFileCpt.FDateTime:= TFile.GetLastWriteTime(FilePathnameI);
                  FCumSize:= FCumSize + FileSize;
                  FCumFileCount:= FCumFileCount + 1;
                end;
            except
              on E: Exception do
                begin
                  E.Message:= 'Error in TFolder.ReadFX processing file "'
                     + FilePathnameI + '"' + #13#10
                     + '(' + E.Message + ')';
                end;
            end;
          end;
      end;
  end;
```

Unfortunately, when I call `TFolder.ReadFX()` for `Pathanme= ‘C:\\Users\User XXX'` on Windows 7, a runtime exception is always thrown when an open file presumably opened by the Windows OS is encountered.

In conclusion, can any one help with the following questions:

1. How to obtain the size of a file without having to open the file stream
2. How to determine whether or not the file is already/in use
3. In the case of a folder, how to extract the name of lowest level folder from the folder path, without manually parsing the path.

Comment: 1. What exactly about `FindFirst/Next()` is not working for you on Android? 2. Don't try to determine if a file is in use before opening it, that just creates a race condition. Open the file and handle the error as needed. 3. I don't understand that question.

Comment: @Remy 1:When FindFirst/FindNext are used to find all the files and sub-folders in a folder, an incomplete set is obtained on an Android platform, but a complete set on a Windows platform. 2. Thank you for the guidance - so is the procedure I posted to get the size of a file OK? 3. To answer your question by an example: If the path of a folder is say Path= 'C:\\Users\Public\Favorites', then what Delphi RTL function may be used to extract the last folder in the path, in this example,  'Favorites'?

Comment: 1. then file a bug report with Embarcadero. 2. sure. Though you may want to see if `TFileStream.Create(FilePathname, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone)` helps. It will still fail if the file is open without read sharing, though. 3. `ExtractTrailingPathDelimiter()` followed by `ExtractFilePath()` or `ExtractFileDir()`